# Problems of using curl on windows compared to mac

Tags: php, windows, macos, curl, xampp

i use xampp apache to run some of my php files.

In one of my php file i use curl to get data from external website, on my windows machine, everything works fine. However, on my mac machine, my browser just can not run those files.. it just takes very long to load, and in the end stop loading.

Attached is one of my php file:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
'http://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print $contents;
?>
```

I am really desprate on why mac machine can not run these files? is there another way to go about doing this on a mac machine? THanks all for your help!

EDIT: [SOLVED] Thanks all for your help. Manage to solve it, due, to because i am connecting to the net using a proxy server...thus my script need to handle that.

Code used:

```
<?php
$aContext = array(
'http' => array(
'proxy' =>'tcp://xxxxx:xx',
'request_fulluri' => true,
),
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

$content = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com", False, $csContext);

print $content;
?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error or warning?

Comment: no. did not receive any warning even when i turn on my debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');`

Comment: Ok manage to do it already. DO not have my mac machine with me.. will try it when i get it. then update you guys thanks :)

hi ajreal.. how do i put the data into a .txt file?

i cant do this? 

$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');

thanks

Comment: `file_get_contents` is to read, and `file_put_contents` to write

Comment: hi, after running it, it still does not work.

this time wif a timeout saying it fail to open stream.

Comment: @Jonathan Low - this mean the page you trying to get is some how broken, had you try to use browser to open that url ? It might return some information ... **OR** simply do a try on `curl -iv url` in command line

Comment: yea i tried the URL on the browser and it take bout 1-3 seconds to load.
tried running the command, it just state it is trying to connect to the IP address of that particular webpage and after a while it couldn't connect to host

the funny thing is that on my window machine, it work perfectly fine.

Comment: isit because my mac is connecting to the net through a proxy server? is there anyway i can use curl to connect wif a proxy server?

Comment: @Jonathan Low - yup, possible. There are options for proxy for curl as well

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the CURL extension installed on your MAC machine. Check that by running a php script with phpinfo(); in it and see if you have the CURL installed/enabled.

Comment: i thought i just have to remove the ';' infront of curl_extension in php.ini file?

Comment: Double check to see if it is working. You may not have the extension files needed. Or they could be not working.